# Python custom string to dict

Tags: python

is there any smart way to convert python string in a format:
`"name=text;name2=text2;name3=text3"` 
to python dict?

Maybe something with json.loads, but I'm not sure...

ANSWER:
so the smartest solution found so far is:

```
result = dict((a.strip(), b.strip())  
     for a, b in (element.split('=')  
           for element in oryginal_text.split(';')))
```

Comment: split by `';'` and then split by `'='`?

Comment: Anything from splitting up to a parser solution - have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: It’s not JSON and also no other established format, so no, existing parsers won’t help.

Comment: Thanks, sure, I can tokenize it etc, but I wondered if there is anything built-in.. :)

Comment: Can you provide some example about what you currently have and what you need?

Comment: @HarshadPatil - I've provided one (working) solution in the original question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
string = "name=text;name2=text2;name3=text3"

args = dict(i.split('=') for i in string.split(';'))
print(args) # {'name': 'text', 'name2': 'text2', 'name3': 'text3'}
```